# Javascript forcing csv file reload (amcharts)

Tags: javascript, caching, csv, amcharts

I am using apache on a raspberry pi to host a page for viewing on an internal network. The page consists of an amcharts graph displaying data from a csv file. The csv file updates every minute. Is there a way of forcing the graph to update?

I've already tried the following methods:
Using the meta tag in the html reload
Using setTimeout in the javascript to force reload.

The first method didn't work, the second works in some browsers (but not IE, which is what I need it to work in!)

Basically, I need the browser to not cache the referenced csv file. Any suggestions much appreciated! I've included the js that references the csv file below, and can include the whole page if necessary.

Thanks

```
            loadCSV("daily.csv");
        });

        function loadCSV(file) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                var request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            // load
            request.open('GET', file, false);
            request.send();
            parseCSV(request.responseText);
        }

        function parseCSV(data) {
            //replace UNIX new lines
            data = data.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
            //replace MAC new lines
            data = data.replace(/\r/g, "\n");
            //split into rows
            var rows = data.split("\n");

            // loop through all rows
            for (var i = 9; i < 19; i++) {
                // this line helps to skip empty rows
                if (rows[i]) {
                    // our columns are separated by comma
                    var column = rows[i].split(",");
                    // column is array now

                    // first item is date
                    var time = column[0];
                    // second item is value of the second column
                    var value = column[1];
                    // third item is in the fourth column
                    var value2 = column[5];

                    var value3 = column[3];

                    // create object which contains all these items:
                    var dataObject = {
                        time: time,
                        actual: value,
                        target: value2,
                        scrap: value3
                    };
                    // add object to chartData array
                    chartData.push(dataObject);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try appending an random variable at the end of url.

```
loadCSV("daily.csv?q="+Math.random());
```

Comment: It took me time to understand why this works. You may want to add to your answer that everything after the question mark does not change the request url. That would help noobs like me a lot ;)